# Adding module to Parse Server

Tags: ios, node.js, twilio, parse-cloud-code, parse-server

I am running the `Parse Server` on `Heroku` and I use `Cloud Code` to verify users via SMS. I use `Twilio` send the SMS messages.

As I understand it I have to add the `Twilio` module so I can use it in my app but I have no idea how to add a dependency. So far I have run `npm install Twilio` and now I'm not sure what to do. Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

As the Parse Server now runs on Node.js, you can install dependencies and use them as if you were building a normal Node.js application. This is good because the included version of the Twilio helper library on Parse was out of date.

So, inside your application directory you should install the twilio module using npm.

```
$ npm install twilio --save
```

This will include the twilio module in your package.json.

Then, in your application you can include the twilio module like so:

```
var twilio = require("twilio");
```

And to send an SMS message, you need to create an API client with your Twilio Account SID and Auth Token (available in your [account portal](https://www.twilio.com/user/account/messaging/dashboard)) and you can then send messages, like this:

```
var twilio = require("twilio");
var client = twilio(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);

client.messages.create({
  to: PHONE_NUMBER,
  from: TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER,
  body: "Hello from Twilio
});
```

There is a more in depth explanation of [how to use the Twilio Node.js module on the Twilio blog](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2013/03/introducing-the-twilio-module-for-node-js.html). Also, check out the [Twilio Node.js module documentation](https://twilio.github.io/twilio-node/).